# Interface inheriting interface

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a hierarchy.

```
public interface IIncomingMessage : IMessage
{
    String Source { get; set; }
    void ProcessMessage();
}


public interface IOutgoingMessages : IMessage
{
    void SendMessage();
}
```

I have a client that uses a Static CreateMessage method to generate my message.

```
IMessage message = MessageFactory.CreateMessage("incomingA");
messageA.ProcessMessage();
```

However the only way I can do this is if I add ProcessMessage() to IMessage. However if I do this then I must implement this in IOutgoingMessage.

Now as I write this I see that I could just get rid of IMessage.. should I? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Perhaps the simplest way of resolving this is two have two methods: `CreateInboundMessage` and `CreateOutboundMessage`

Comment: Just a quick reminder: interfaces **extend** each other.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of interfaces, but what I'm not seeing is the intent behind them. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why are you *describing* all your code rather than just providing a short but complete example which *demonstrates* it?

Comment: @T.Kiley, I am border-line ready to rollback your edit, but the code sample is so simple it should be ok. But try to avoid "putting words in someone's mouth". This is **not** the OP's code.

Comment: +1 @JonSkeet Code is worth a thousand words

Comment: @gunr2171 I was trying to avoid that, but since the OP text was just describing exactly that code, I thought it would be simpler to read.

Comment: Good point Jon Skeet. and thanks to T. Kiley for updating my original query. Having read your comments and thought further on what I'm actually trying to achieve, there is no need for IMessage (at least not at the minute). I also like T. Kiley's suggestion of two methods. Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on how you're using the `CreateMessage` factory, you are expecting that `ProcessMessage` is a common method to all `IMessage` types.  Based on how you expect your code to work, I would say that `IMessage` should have a `ProcessMessage` method interface defined.

However, in looking at the small snippet of code, it seems to me that your intent is not to always process a message, but only do so if it's an `IIncomingMessage` implementation.  So your factory approach isn't going to work.  T. Kiley's suggestion of having two factory methods of `CreateInboundMessage` and `CreateOutboundMessage` may make more sense since you have different behaviors for both types of messages.  Those methods then would return `IIncomingMessage` and 'IOutgoingMessage` instances and then you can process them or handle them accordingly.

`IMessage` is being used, currently, as a marker interface.  If you see a need for this - whether it's a constraint for generics (e.g. `MyCollection<T> where T : IMessage`), then keep it.  But if it's really not describing behavior or a common set of properties/methods or if it's not to be used as a useful marker, then I'm not sure what benefit it provides.

Again, this is based off just seeing a little bit of code.  I'm assuming there's more behavior and functionality behind the scenes.   Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to simplify by giving another example of this scenario:

```
public class Animal
{
    void Run();
}

public class Giraffe : Animal
{
    void ExtendNeck();
}

public class Monkey : Animal
{
    void EatBanana();
}
```

Now is it okay if I now add `EatBanana()` to `Animal`? As you noticed yourself, not all `IMessage` implementors `ProcessMessage()` and in this example not all animals `EatBanana()`. What is another way to accomplish what you are trying to do? Only use `IMessage` if you do have common functionalities to be shared among your classes. If you don't have any, there is no need for an inteface. Have YAGNI in mind. You may add it later if there are common functionalities. If you want to create an `IncomingMessage` and call `IncomingMessage` specific methods, then just create a strongly typed `IncomingMessage` and work with it. You may not even need a static factory method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different classes which don't inherit anything and completely separate the process. If you do that you will loose several advantages of using subclassing in this case. There might be similar properties between them which will make it easier to reference one versus the other if they both extend a common class. As for your method issue with these subclasses, you can simply have your parent class declare a common method (let's call it `ProcessMessage()` ), and simply have each subclass overwrite the behavior of such method. This way you don't need to have to different methods but simply two different definitions. Simple polymorphism concepts.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming 'MessageFactory.CreateMessage("incomingA")' return an object of type IIncomingMessage)

either use var

```
var message = MessageFactory.CreateMessage("incomingA");
message.ProcessMessage();
```

or cast the result

```
IMessage message = MessageFactory.CreateMessage("incomingA");

     if (!(message is IIncommingMessage))
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

     (message as IIncommingMessage).ProcessMessage();
```

Comment: Although this approach would work. I think it's kind of ugly. With better design, OP doesn't have to put these types of checks all over the place.

Comment: I agree, but I was just trying to answer the question - not criticize the design.